# Google chrome is returning window.parent.frames.length value one more than other browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When I alert, alert(window.parent.frames.length) on my form, chrome returns wrong number of frames. Chrome returns 1 more than any browser returns which is wrong. My frame-set contains max 3 frames but it return 4. This is becoming issue when I want to decide my target frame based on number of frames present.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why you may have more frames than expected.

My suggestion is that you add a class to the frames you own and count the frames that only have that class, for example:

```
<frame class="test"></frame>
<frame class="test"></frame>

...

<script>
    var count = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<window.parent.frames.length; i++)
        if(window.parent.frames[i].className == "test")
            count++;
    alert(count);
</script>
```

**PS:** Slightly off-topic, but why are you using frames? The technology sorta died years ago.

Comment: I have a frame set and fixed frame design, and I'm testing on 3 other  browsers(firefox, safari and IE) and it is returning correct value. Only chrome is returning the value 1 more than all other browsers

Comment: You already said that. Either you modify your code, or you re-engineer Chrome. :)

Comment: Anything would work for me as far I'm getting same value across all browsers :) I checked and I have no additional frames.

Comment: Read the answer. If you add a class to all your own frames and count those, you will get a correct count, not including the mystery extra frame.

Comment: Actually I have nearly 100 applications where this is happening..not possible to make the changes in all of them. This has started happening recently after version 30 of chrome. Is there any other way to take the count of frames?

Comment: Yes, sort of: `document.getElementsByTagName('FRAME').length` But I suspect you will be getting the same value. I mean, if there are three frames, there's no changing it.